# How to include newline on objective-c when reading from resource string

Tags: objective-c, string, resources, newline

When using a string 
`NSString *Content = @"mytestline one \n My second line";` 
`MyTextView1.text = Content;`
the textview prints out 2 lines correctly.

When reading the same string from resource
`NSString *Content = ReadMyStringClass` 
`MyTextView1.text = Content;`

TextView only print out one single line with content of unescaped characters "\n" included.
How to create newline on Textview?

[image: XML File]

Code of ReadMyStringClass

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XmlDictionary.plist"];
NSDictionary *XmlDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: finalPath];

NSString *WelcomeText = [XmlDictionary objectForKey:@"WelcomeMessage"];
```

Comment: I've updateded the question regarding your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the string in the plist file. It doesn't contain a new line character but the two characters `\` and `n`. So you should either 1) edit the plist file, and insert *"real"* new line characters by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd> or 2) change the occurrences of `\n` programmatically.

```
NSString *WelcomeText = [[XmlDictionary objectForKey:@"WelcomeMessage"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: Ok, didn't recognize, that the string was converted to `\\n`. Thanks for advice!